# Pool mining through the TOR network?

Tags: mining-pools, tor

Is it possible to mine Bitcoins at a pool through the TOR network? If so, how would one configure the appropriate tools?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: @Shamoon mostly something that came up during a conversation I had with my academic supervisor - he likes pointing out all possible exploits that could happen in relation to Bitcoin and one of them was attacking miners based on their IPs. So I figured out I'd investigate possible obfuscation of the addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mine over TOR, but I would expect you would get much higher stales & downtime due to the high latencies of the TOR network.

You can use the application ProxyChains to force any application on your computer to use a proxy (or a combination of proxies), simply add a new proxy to ProxyChains, 127.0.0.1 as IP and your TOR software's port as port, and then setup Proxychains to force your mining application to use that proxy.

http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

[Eligius has a hidden service for Tor mining.](http://eligius.st/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_mine_over_Tor.3F)

Comment: Well, they used to.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an application to accomplish this on my own time. 
Hoping this helps you and anyone else who comes across this answer.

https://github.com/Elycin/PoolOverSocks5

The test results that I've used over tor and the stratum protocol, I seem to have an average latency of 610ms to a Monero Pool such as `pool.usxmrpool.com`. This may vary for other cryptocurrencies, but using Tor there is no stales in 4 hours of testing.

Here's a image of it all working in my test environment:
[image]

Cheers.